# Using an js animation exported with bodymovin in after effects for html

Tags: javascript, html, css, liquid, preloader

I have a preloader written with js and html. It works fine and it plays, after the DOM content is loaded as it should. Now I found a more reliable solution, using a js animation I exported with bodymovin. Now my question is how to implement this. I'm not completely familiar with javascript but I do the best I can. I appreciate any answers.
Below you find my code and what I want to add.

```js
function hidePreloader() {
  var preloader = document.getElementById('preloader');
  var mpreloaderw = document.getElementById('mpreloader-wrapper');

  preloader.style.display = 'none';
  mpreloaderw.style.display = 'none';
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  var animatedGIF = document.getElementById('preloaderimg');
  var manimatedGIF = document.getElementById('mpreloaderimg');
  if (document.cookie.indexOf("preloaderShown=true") === -1) {
        document.cookie = "preloaderShown=true; path=/";
    // Assuming animatedGIF is defined
    window.onload = function() {
      
      if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
    manimatedGIF.style.setProperty('visibility', 'visible', 'important');
        manimatedGIF.src = "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0773/2494/3684/files/probieren.webp?v=1701169262";
        
      } else{
        animatedGIF.src = "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0773/2494/3684/files/webp_logo_fuer_web.webp?v=1698168691";
        animatedGIF.style.setProperty('visibility', 'visible', 'important');
      }
      
      setTimeout(function() {
      hidePreloader();
    }, 3000);
    };


  } else {
    // If the preloader has already been shown in this session, hide it immediately
    $('#preloader,#preloader-wrapper, #mpreloader, #mpreloader-wrapper, #mpreloaderimg').hide();
    $('#preloader, #mpreloader').css('background-color', 'transparent');
  }
});
```

```css
#preloader{
  background-color: #f7f7f0;
  width: 100% !important;
  z-index: 103;
  height: 100% !important;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  
} 

#preloader img{
  width: 70% !Important;
  z-index: 101;
}
#mpreloader img{
  width: 100% !Important;
  z-index: 101; 
}



@media screen and (max-width: 932px){

  
#mpreloader-wrapper, #shortloader-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f7f7f0;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
}
}
#mpreloader{
  height: 100% !important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100% !important;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 102;
  display: flex;  
}

@media screen and (max-height: 845px){
  #mpreloader{
    top: -15% !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
{
  #preloader{
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 599px){
  #mpreloader{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- {% if {{globals.visitor.deviceClass}} == 'desktop' -%} -->
    <link rel="preload" fetchpriority="high" as="image" href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0773/2494/3684/files/webp_logo_fuer_web.webp?v=1698168691" type="image/webp">
<!-- {% else %} -->
     <link rel="preload" fetchpriority="high" as="image" href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0773/2494/3684/files/probieren.webp?v=1701169262" type="image/webp">
<!--    {% endif %} -->
<!--     {% if template.name == "index" %}  -->
    
      <div id="preloader">
       <img src="" id="preloaderimg" style="visibility: hidden;">
      </div>
      <div id="mpreloader-wrapper">
    <div id="mpreloader">
      <img src="" id="mpreloaderimg" style="visibility: hidden;">
    </div>
        </div>
 <!--      {% endif %} -->
```

So instead of playing the webp files I want to use this js animation:

````
!function(t,e){"object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module?module.exports=e():"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(e):(t="undefined"!=typeof globalThis?globalThis:t||self).lottie=e()}(this,(function(){"use strict";var svgNS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",locationHref="",_useWebWorker=!1,initialDefaultFrame=-999999,setWebWorker=function(t){_useWebWorker=!!t},getWebWorker=function(){return _useWebWorker},setLocationHref=function(t){locationHref=t},getLocationHref=function(){return locationHref};function createTag(t){return document.createElement(t)}function extendPrototype(t,e){var r,i,s=t.length;for(r=0;r<s;r+=1)for(var a in i=t[r].prototype)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(i,a)&&(e.prototype[a]=i[a])}function getDescriptor(t,e){return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(t,e)}function createProxyFunction(t){function e(){}return e.prototype=t,e}var audioControllerFactory=function(){function t(t){this.audios=[],this.audioFactory=t,this._volume=1,this._isMuted=!1}return t.prototype={addAudio:function(t){this.audios.push(t)},pause:function(){var t,e=this.audios.length;for(t=0;t<e;t+=1)this.audios[t].pause()},resume:function(){var t,e=this.audios.length;for(t=0;t<e;t+=1)this.audios[t].resume()},setRate:function(t){var e,r=this.audios.length;for(e=0;e<r;e+=1)this.audios[e].setRate(t)},createAudio:function(t){return this.audioFactory?this.audioFactory(t):window.Howl?new window.Howl({src:[t]}):{isPlaying:!1,play:function(){this.isPlaying=!0},seek:function(){this.isPlaying=!1},playing:function(){},rate:function(){},setVolume:function(){}}},setAudioFactory:function(t){this.audioFactory=t},setVolume:function(t){this._volume=t,this._updateVolume()},mute:function(){this._isMuted=!0,this._updateVolume()},unmute:function(){this._isMuted=!1,this._updateVolume()},getVolume:function(){return this._volume},_updateVolume:function(){var t,e=this.audios.length;for(t=0;t<e;t+=1)this.audios[t].volume(this._volume*(this._isMuted?0:1))}},function(){return new t}}(),createTypedArray=function(){function t(t,e){var r,i=0,s=[];switch(t){case"int16":case"uint8c":r=1;break;default:r=1.1}for(i=0;i<e;i+=1)s.push(r);return s}return"function"==typeof Uint8ClampedArray&&"function"==typeof Float32Array?function(e,r){return"float32"===e?new Float32Array(r):"int16"===e?new Int16Array(r):"uint8c"===e?new Uint8ClampedArray(r):t(e,r)}:t}();function createSizedArray(t){return Array.apply(null,{length:t})}function _typeof$6(t){return _typeof$6="function"==typeof Symbol&&"symbol"==typeof Symbol.iterator?function(t){return typeof t}:function(t){return t&&"function"==typeof Symbol&&t.constructor===Symbol&&t!==Symbol.prototype?"symbol":typeof t},_typeof$6(t)}var subframeEnabled=!0,expressionsPlugin=null,idPrefix="",isSafari=/^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent),_shouldRoundValues=!1,bmPow=Math.pow,bmSqrt=Math.sqrt,bmFloor=Math.floor,bmMax=Math.max,bmMin=Math.min,BMMath={};function ProjectInterface$1(){return{}}!function(){var t,e=["abs","acos","acosh","asin","asinh","atan","atanh","atan2","ceil","cbrt","expm1","clz32","cos","cosh","exp","floor","fround","hypot","imul","log","log1p","log2","log10","max","min","pow","random","round","sign","sin","sinh","sqrt","tan","tanh","trunc","E","LN10","LN2","LOG10E","LOG2E","PI","SQRT1_2","SQRT2"],r=e.length;for(t=0;t<r;t+=1)BMMath[e[t]]=Math[e[t]]}(),BMMath.random=Math.random,BMMath.abs=function(t){if("object"===_typeof$6(t)&&t.length){var e,r=createSizedArray(t.length),i=t.length;for(e=0;e<i;e+=1)r[e]=Math.abs(t[e]);return r}return Math.abs(t)};var defaultCurveSegments=150,degToRads=Math.PI/180,roundCorner=.5519;function roundValues(t){_shouldRoundValues=!!t}function bmRnd(t){return _shouldRoundValues?Math.round(t):t}function styleDiv(t){t.style.position="absolute",t.style.top=0,t.style.left=0,t.style.display="block",t.style.transformOrigin="0 0",t.style.webkitTransformOrigin="0 0",t.style.backfaceVisibility="visible",t.style.webkitBackfaceVisibility="visible",t.style.transformStyle="preserve-3d",t.style.webkitTransformStyle="preserve-3d",t.style.mozTransformStyle="preserve-3d"}function BMEnterFrameEvent(t,e,r,i){this.type=t,this.currentTime=e,this.totalTime=r,this.direction=i<0?-1:1}function BMCompleteEvent(t,e){this.type=t,this.direction=e<0?-1:1}function BMCompleteLoopEvent(t,e,r,i){this.type=t,this.currentLoop=r,this.totalLoops=e,this.direction=i<0?-1:1}function BMSegmentStartEvent(t,e,r){this.type=t,this.firstFrame=e,this.totalFrames=r}function BMDestroyEvent(t,e){this.type=t,this.target=e}function BMRenderFrameErrorEvent(t,e){this.type="renderFrameError",this.nativeError=t,this.currentTime=e}function BMConfigErrorEvent(t){this.type="configError",this.nativeError=t}function BMAnimationConfigErrorEvent(t,e){this.type=t,this.nativeError=e}var createElementID=(_count=0,function(){return idPrefix+"__lottie_element_"+(_count+=1)}),_count;function HSVtoRGB(t,e,r){var i,s,a,n,o,h,l,p;switch(h=r*(1-e),l=r*(1-(o=6*t-(n=Math.floor(6*t)))*e),p=r*(1-(1-o)*e),n%6){case 0:i=r,s=p,a=h;break;case 1:i=l,s=r,a=h;break;case 2:i=h,s=r,a=p;break;case 3:i=h,s=l,a=r;break;case 4:i=p,s=h,a=r;break;case 5:i=r,s=h,a=l}return[i,s,a]}function RGBtoHSV(t,e,r){var i,s=Math.max(t,e,r),a=Math.min(t,e,r),n=s-a,o=0===s?0:n/s,h=s/255;switch(s){case a:i=0;break;case t:i=e-r+n*(e<r?6:0),i/=6*n;break;case e:i=r-t+2*n,i/=6*n;break;case r:i=t-e+4*n,i/=6*n}return[i,o,h]}function addSaturationToRGB(t,e){var r=RGBtoHSV(255*t[0],255*t[1],255*t[2]);return r[1]+=e,r[1]>1?r[1]=1:r[1]<=0&&(r[1]=0),HSVtoRGB(r[0],r[1],r[2])}function addBrightnessToRGB(t,e){var r=RGBtoHSV(255*t[0],255*t[1],255*t[2]);return r[2]+=e,r[2]>1?r[2]=1:r[2]<0&&(r[2]=0),HSVtoRGB(r[0],r[1],r[2])}function addHueToRGB(t,e){var r=RGBtoHSV(255*t[0],255*t[1],255*t[2]);return r[0]+=e/360,r[0]>1?r[0]-=1:r[0]<0&&(r[0]+=1),HSVtoRGB(r[0],r[1],r[2])}var rgbToHex=function(){var t,e,r=[];for(t=0;t<256;t+=1)e=t.toString(16),r[t]=1===e.length?"0"+e:e;return function(t,e,i){return t<0&&(t=0),e<0&&(e=0),i<0&&(i=0),"#"+r[t]+r[e]+r[i]}}(),setSubframeEnabled=function(t){subframeEnabled=!!t},getSubframeEnabled=function(){return subframeEnabled},setExpressionsPlugin=function(t){expressionsPlugin=t},getExpressionsPlugin=function(){return expressionsPlugin},setDefaultCurveSegments=function(t){defaultCurveSegments=t},getDefaultCurveSegments=function(){return defaultCurveSegments},setIdPrefix=function(t){idPrefix=t},getIdPrefix=function(){return idPrefix};function createNS(t){return document.createElementNS(svgNS,t)}function _typeof$5(t){return _typeof$5="function"==typeof Symbol&&"symbol"==typeof Symbol.iterator?function(t){return typeof t}:function(t){return t&&"function"==typeof Symbol&&t.constructor===Symbol&&t!==Symbol.prototype?"symbol":typeof t},_typeof$5(t)}var dataManager=function(){var t,e,r=1,i=[],s={onmessage:function(){},postMessage:function(e){t({data:e})}},a={postMessage:function(t){s.onmessage({data:t})}};function n(){e||(e=function(e){if(window.Worker&&window.Blob&&getWebWorker()){var r=new Blob(["var _workerSelf = self; self.onmessage = ",e.toString()],{type:"text/javascript"}),i=URL.createObjectURL(r);return new Worker(i)}return t=e,s}((function(t){if(a.dataManager||(a.dataManager=function(){function t(s,a){var n,o,h,l,p,m,c=s.length;for(o=0;o<c;o+=1)if("ks"in(n=s[o])&&!n.completed){if(n.completed=!0,n.tt&&(s[o-1].td=n.tt),n.hasMask){var d=n.masksProperties;for(l=d.length,h=0;h<l;h+=1)if(d[h].pt.k.i)i(d[h].pt.k);else for(m=d[h].pt.k.length,p=0;p<m;p+=1)d[h].pt.k[p].s&&i(d[h].pt.k[p].s[0]),d[h].pt.k[p].e&&i(d[h].pt.k[p].e[0])}0===n.ty?(n.layers=e(n.refId,a),t(n.layers,a)):4===n.ty?r(n.shapes):5===n.ty&&f(n)}}function e(t,e){var r=function(t,e){for(var r=0,i=e.length;r<i;){if(e[r].id===t)return e[r];r+=1}return null}(t,e);return r?r.layers.__used?JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(r.layers)):(r.layers.__used=!0,r.layers):null}function r(t){var e,s,a;for(e=t.length-1;e>=0;e-=1)if("sh"===t[e].ty)if(t[e].ks.k.i)i(t[e].ks.k);else for(a=t[e].ks.k.length,s=0;s<a;s+=1)t[e].ks.k[s].s&&i(t[e].ks.k[s].s[0]),t[e].ks.k[s].e&&i(t[e].ks.k[s].e[0]);else"gr"===t[e].ty&&r(t[e].it)}function i(t){var e,r=t.i.length;for(e=0;e<r;e+=1)t.i[e][0]+=t.v[e][0],t.i[e][1]+=t.v[e][1],t.o[e][0]+=t.v[e][0],t.o[e][1]+=t.v[e][1]}function s(t,e){var r=e?e.split("."):[100,100,100];return t[0]>r[0]||!(r[0]>t[0])&&(t[1]>r[1]||!(r[1]>t[1])&&(t[2]>r[2]||!(r[2]>t[2])&&null))}var a,n=function(){var t=[4,4,14];function e(t){var e,r,i,s=t.length;for(e=0;e<s;e+=1)5===t[e].ty&&(i=void 0,i=(r=t[e]).t.d,r.t.d={k:[{s:i,t:0}]})}return function(r){if(s(t,r.v)&&(e(r.layers),r.assets)){var i,a=r.assets.length;for(i=0;i<a;i+=1)r.assets[i].layers&&e(r.assets[i].layers)}}}(),o=(a=[4,7,99],function(t){if(t.chars&&!s(a,t.v)){var e,i=t.chars.length;for(e=0;e<i;e+=1){var n=t.chars[e];n.data&&n.data.shapes&&(r(n.data.shapes),n.data.ip=0,n.data.op=99999,n.data.st=0,n.data.sr=1,n.data.ks={p:{k:[0,0],a:0},s:{k:[100,100],a:0},a:{k:[0,0],a:0},r:{k:0,a:0},o:{k:100,a:0}},t.chars[e].t||(n.data.shapes.push({ty:"no"}),n.data.shapes[0].it.push({p:{k:[0,0],a:0},s:{k:[100,100],a:0},a:{k:[0,0],a:0},r:{k:0,a:0},o:{k:100,a:0},sk:{k:0,a:0},sa:{k:0,a:0},ty:"tr"})))}}}),h=function(){var t=[5,7,15];function e(t){var e,r,i=t.length;for(e=0;e<i;e+=1)5===t[e].ty&&(r=void 0,"number"==typeof(r=t[e].t.p).a&&(r.a={a:0,k:r.a}),"number"==typeof r.p&&(r.p={a:0,k:r.p}),"number"==typeof r.r&&(r.r={a:0,k:r.r}))}return function(r){if(s(t,r.v)&&(e(r.layers),r.assets)){var i,a=r.assets.length;for(i=0;i<a;i+=1)r.assets[i].layers&&e(r.assets[i].layers)}}}(),l=function(){var t=[4,1,9];function e(t){var r,i,s,a=t.length;for(r=0;r<a;r+=1)if("gr"===t[r].ty)e(t[r].it);else if("fl"===t[r].ty||"st"===t[r].ty)if(t[r].c.k&&t[r].c.k[0].i)for(s=t[r].c.k.length,i=0;i<s;i+=1)t[r].c.k[i].s&&(t[r].c.k[i].s[0]/=255,t[r].c.k[i].s[1]/=255,t[r].c.k[i].s[2]/=255,t[r].c.k[i].s[3]/=255),t[r].c.k[i].e&&(t[r].c.k[i].e[0]/=255,t[r].c.k[i].e[1]/=255,t[r].c.k[i].e[2]/=255,t[r].c.k[i].e[3]/=255);else t[r].c.k[0]/=255,t[r].c.k[1]/=255,t[r].c.k[2]/=255,t[r].c.k[3]/=255}function r(t){var r,i=t.length;for(r=0;r<i;r+=1)4===t[r].ty&&e(t[r].shapes)}return function(e){if(s(t,e.v)&&(r(e.layers),e.assets)){var i,a=e.assets.length;for(i=0;i<a;i+=1)e.assets[i].layers&&r(e.assets[i].layers)}}}(),p=function(){var t=[4,4,18];function e(t){var r,i,s;for(r=t.length-1;r>=0;r-=1)if("sh"===t[r].ty)if(t[r].ks.k.i)t[r].ks.k.c=t[r].closed;else for(s=t[r].ks.k.length,i=0;i<s;i+=1)t[r].ks.k[i].s&&(t[r].ks.k[i].s[0].c=t[r].closed),t[r].ks.k[i].e&&(t[r].ks.k[i].e[0].c=t[r].closed);else"gr"===t[r].ty&&e(t[r].it)}function r(t){var r,i,s,a,n,o,h=t.length;for(i=0;i<h;i+=1){if((r=t[i]).hasMask){var l=r.masksProperties;for(a=l.length,s=0;s<a;s+=1)if(l[s].pt.k.i)l[s].pt.k.c=l[s].cl;else for(o=l[s].pt.k.length,n=0;n<o;n+=1)l[s].pt.k[n].s&&(l[s].pt.k[n].s[0].c=l[s].cl),l[s].pt.k[n].e&&(l[s].pt.k[n].e[0].c=l[s].cl)}4===r.ty&&e(r.shapes)}}return function(e){if(s(t,e.v)&&(r(e.layers),e.assets)){var i,a=e.assets.length;for(i=0;i<a;i+=1)e.assets[i].layers&&r(e.assets[i].layers)}}}();function f(t){0===t.t.a.length&&t.t.p}var m={completeData:function(r){r.__complete||(l(r),n(r),o(r),h(r),p(r),t(r.layers,r.assets),function(r,i){if(r){var s=0,a=r.length;for(s=0;s<a;s+=1)1===r[s].t&&(r[s].data.layers=e(r[s].data.refId,i),t(r[s].data.layers,i))}}(r.chars,r.assets),r.__complete=!0)}};return m.checkColors=l,m.checkChars=o,m.checkPathProperties=h,m.checkShapes=p,m.completeLayers=t,m}()),a.assetLoader||(a.assetLoader=function(){function t(t){var e=t.getResponseHeader("content-type");return e&&"json"===t.responseType&&-1!==e.indexOf("json")||t.response&&"object"===_typeof$5(t.response)?t.response:t.response&&"string"==typeof t.response?JSON.parse(t.response):t.responseText?JSON.parse(t.responseText):null}return{load:function(e,r,i,s){var a,n=new XMLHttpRequest;try{n.responseType="json"}catch(t){}n.onreadystatechange=function(){if(4===n.readyState)if(200===n.status)a=t(n),i(a);else try{a=t(n),i(a)}catch(t){s&&s(t)}};try{n.open("GET",e,!0)}catch(t){n.open("GET",r+"/"+e,!0)}n.send()}}}()),"loadAnimation"===t.data.type)a.assetLoader.load(t.data.path,t.data.fullPath,(function(e){a.dataManager.completeData(e),a.postMessage({id:t.data.id,payload:e,status:"success"})}),(function(){a.postMessage({id:t.data.id,status:"error"})}));else if("complete"===t.data.type){var e=t.data.animation;a.dataManager.completeData(e),a.postMessage({id:t.data.id,payload:e,status:"success"})}else"loadData"===t.data.type&&a.assetLoader.load(t.data.path,t.data.fullPath,(function(e){a.postMessage({id:t.data.id,payload:e,status:"success"})}),(function(){a.postMessage({id:t.data.id,status:"error"})}))})),e.onmessage=function(t){var e=t.data,r=e.id,s=i[r];i[r]=null,"success"===e.status?s.onComplete(e.payload):s.onError&&s.onError()})}function o(t,e){var s="processId_"+(r+=1);return i[s]={onComplete:t,onError:e},s}return{loadAnimation:function(t,r,i){n();var s=o(r,i);e.postMessage({type:"loadAnimation",path:t,fullPath:window.location.origin+window.location.pathname,id:s})},loadData:function(t,r,i){n();var s=o(r,i);e.postMessage({type:"loadData",path:t,fullPath:window.location.origin+window.location.pathname,id:s})},completeAnimation:function(t,r,i){n();var s=o(r,i);e.postMessage({type:"complete",animation:t,id:s})}}}(),ImagePreloader=function(){var t=function(){var t=createTag("canvas");t.width=1,t.height=1;var e=t.getContext("2d");return e.fillStyle="rgba(0,0,0,0)",e.fillRect(0,0,1,1),t}();function e(){this.loadedAssets+=1,this.loadedAssets===this.totalImages&&this.loadedFootagesCount===this.totalFootages&&this.imagesLoadedCb&&this.imagesLoadedCb(null)}function r(){this.loadedFootagesCount+=1,this.loadedAssets===this.totalImages&&this.loadedFootagesCount===this.totalFootages&&this.imagesLoadedCb&&this.imagesLoadedCb(null)}function i(t,e,r){var i="";if(t.e)i=t.p;else if(e){var s=t.p;-1!==s.indexOf("images/")&&(s=s.split("/")[1]),i=e+s}else i=r,i+=t.u?t.u:"",i+=t.p;return i}function s(t){var e=0,r=setInterval(function(){(t.getBBox().width||e>500)&&(this._imageLoaded(),clearInterval(r)),e+=1}.bind(this),50)}function a(t){var e={assetData:t},r=i(t,this.assetsPath,this.path);return dataManager.loadData(r,function(t){e.img=t,this._footageLoaded()}.bind(this),function(){e.img={},this._footageLoaded()}.bind(this)),e}function n(){this._imageLoaded=e.bind(this),this._footageLoaded=r.bind(this),this.testImageLoaded=s.bind(this),this.createFootageData=a.bind(this),this.assetsPath="",this.path="",this.totalImages=0,this.totalFootages=0,this.loadedAssets=0,this.loadedFootagesCount=0,this.imagesLoadedCb=null,this.images=[]}return n.prototype={loadAssets:function(t,e){var r;this.imagesLoadedCb=e;var i=t.length;for(r=0;r<i;r+=1)t[r].layers||(t[r].t&&"seq"!==t[r].t?3===t[r].t&&(this.totalFootages+=1,this.images.push(this.createFootageData(t[r]))):(this.totalImages+=1,this.images.push(this._createImageData(t[r]))))},setAssetsPath:function(t){this.assetsPath=t||""},setPath:function(t){this.path=t||""},loadedImages:function(){return this.totalImages===this.loadedAssets},loadedFootages:function(){return this.totalFootages===this.loadedFootagesCount},destroy:function(){this.imagesLoadedCb=null,this.images.length=0},getAsset:function(t){for(var e=0,r=this.images.length;e<r;){if(this.images[e].assetData===t)return this.images[e].img;e+=1}return null},createImgData:function(e){var r=i(e,this.assetsPath,this.path),s=createTag("img");s.crossOrigin="anonymous",s.addEventListener("load",this._imageLoaded,!1),s.addEventListener("error",function(){a.img=t,this._imageLoaded()}.bind(this),!1),s.src=r;var a={img:s,assetData:e};return a},createImageData:function(e){var r=i(e,this.assetsPath,this.path),s=createNS("image");isSafari?this.testImageLoaded(s):s.addEventListener("load",this._imageLoaded,!1),s.addEventListener("error",function(){a.img=t,this._imageLoaded()}.bind(this),!1),s.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink","href",r),this._elementHelper.append?this._elementHelper.append(s):this._elementHelper.appendChild(s);var a={img:s,assetData:e};return a},imageLoaded:e,footageLoaded:r,setCacheType:function(t,e){"svg"===t?(this._elementHelper=e,this._createImageData=this.createImageData.bind(this)):this._createImageData=this.createImgData.bind(this)}},n}();function BaseEvent(){}BaseEvent.prototype={triggerEvent:function(t,e){if(this._cbs[t])for(var r=this._cbs[t],i=0;i<r.length;i+=1)r[i](e)},addEventListener:function(t,e){return this._cbs[t]||(this._cbs[t]=[]),this._cbs[t].push(e),function(){this.removeEventListener(t,e)}.bind(this)},removeEventListener:function(t,e){if(e){if(this._cbs[t]){for(var r=0,i=this._cbs[t].length;r<i;)this._cbs[t][r]===e&&(this._cbs[t].splice(r,1),r-=1,i-=1),r+=1;this._cbs[t].length||(this._cbs[t]=null)}}else this._cbs[t]=null}};var markerParser=function(){function t(t){for(var e,r=t.split("\r\n"),i={},s=0,a=0;a<r.length;a+=1)2===(e=r[a].split(":")).length&&(i[e[0]]=e[1].trim(),s+=1);if(0===s)throw new Error;return i}return function(e){for(var r=[],i=0;i<e.length;i+=1){var s=e[i],a={time:s.tm,duration:s.dr};try{a.payload=JSON.parse(e[i].cm)}catch(r){try{a.payload=t(e[i].cm)}catch(t){a.payload={name:e[i]}}}r.push(a)}return r}}(),ProjectInterface=function(){function t(t){this.compositions.push(t)}return function(){function e(t){for(var e=0,r=this.compositions.length;e<r;){if(this.compositions[e].data&&this.compositions[e].data.nm===t)return this.compositions[e].prepareFrame&&this.compositions[e].data.xt&&this.compositions[e].prepareFrame(this.currentFrame),this.compositions[e].compInterface;e+=1}return null}return e.compositions=[],e.currentFrame=0,e.registerComposition=t,e}}(),renderers={},registerRenderer=function(t,e){renderers[t]=e};function getRenderer(t){return renderers[t]}function _typeof$4(t){return _typeof$4="function"==typeof Symbol&&"symbol"==typeof Symbol.iterator?function(t){return typeof t}:function(t){return t&&"function"==typeof Symbol&&t.constructor===Symbol&&t!==Symbol.prototype?"symbol":typeof t},_typeof$4(t)}var AnimationItem=function(){this._cbs=[],this.name="",this.path="",this.isLoaded=!1,this.currentFrame=0,this.currentRawFrame=0,this.firstFrame=0,this.totalFrames=0,this.frameRate=0,this.frameMult=0,this.playSpeed=1,this.playDirection=1,this.playCount=0,this.animationData={},this.assets=[],this.isPaused=!0,this.autoplay=!1,this.loop=!0,this.renderer=null,this.animationID=createElementID(),this.assetsPath="",this.timeCompleted=0,this.segmentPos=0,this.isSubframeEnabled=getSubframeEnabled(),this.segments=[],this._idle=!0,this._completedLoop=!1,this.projectInterface=ProjectInterface(),this.imagePreloader=new ImagePreloader,this.audioController=audioControllerFactory(),this.markers=[],this.configAnimation=this.configAnimation.bind(this),this.onSetupError=this.onSetupError.bind(this),this.onSegmentComplete=this.onSegmentComplete.bind(this)};extendPrototype([BaseEvent],AnimationItem),AnimationItem.prototype.setParams=function(t){(t.wrapper||t.container)&&(this.wrapper=t.wrapper||t.container);var e="svg";t.animType?e=t.animType:t.renderer&&(e=t.renderer);var r=getRenderer(e);this.renderer=new r(this,t.rendererSettings),this.imagePreloader.setCacheType(e,this.renderer.globalData.defs),this.renderer.setProjectInterface(this.projectInterface),this.animType=e,""===t.loop||null===t.loop||void 0===t.loop||!0===t.loop?this.loop=!0:!1===t.loop?this.loop=!1:this.loop=parseInt(t.loop,10),this.autoplay=!("autoplay"in t)||t.autoplay,this.name=t.name?t.name:"",this.autoloadSegments=!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t,"autoloadSegments")||t.autoloadSegments,this.assetsPath=t.assetsPath,this.initialSegment=t.initialSegment,t.audioFactory&&this.audioController.setAudioFactory(t.audioFactory),t.animationData?this.setupAnimation(t.animationData):t.path&&(-1!==t.path.lastIndexOf("\\")?this.path=t.path.substr(0,t.path.lastIndexOf("\\")+1):this.path=t.path.substr(0,t.path.lastIndexOf("/")+1),this.fileName=t.path.substr(t.path.lastIndexOf("/")+1),this.fileName=this.fileName.substr(0,this.fileName.lastIndexOf(".json")),dataManager.loadAnimation(t.path,this.configAnimation,this.onSetupError))},AnimationItem.prototype.onSetupError=function(){this.trigger("data_failed")},AnimationItem.prototype.setupAnimation=function(t){dataManager.completeAnimation(t,this.configAnimation)},AnimationItem.prototype.setData=function(t,e){e&&"object"!==_typeof$4(e)&&(e=JSON.parse(e));var r={wrapper:t,animationData:e},i=t.attributes;r.path=i.getNamedItem("data-animation-path")?i.getNamedItem("data-animation-path").value:i.getNamedItem("data-bm-path")?i.getNamedItem("data-bm-path").value:i.getNamedItem("bm-path")?i.getNamedItem("bm-path").value:"",r.animType=i.getNamedItem("data-anim-type")?i.getNamedItem("data-anim-type").value:i.getNamedItem("data-bm-type")?i.getNamedItem("data-bm-type").value:i.getNamedItem("bm-type")?i.getNamedItem("bm-type").value:i.getNamedItem("data-bm-renderer")?i.getNamedItem("data-bm-renderer").value:i.getNamedItem("bm-renderer")?i.getNamedItem("bm-renderer").value:"canvas";var s=i.getNamedItem("data-anim-loop")?i.getNamedItem("data-anim-loop").value:i.getNamedItem("data-bm-loop")?i.getNamedItem("data-bm-loop").value:i.getNamedItem("bm-loop")?i.getNamedItem("bm-loop").value:"";"false"===s?r.loop=!1:"true"===s?r.loop=!0:""!==s&&(r.loop=parseInt(s,10));var a=i.getNamedItem("data-anim-autoplay")?i.getNamedItem("data-anim-autoplay").value:i.getNamedItem("data-bm-autoplay")?i.getNamedItem("data-bm-autoplay").value:!i.getNamedItem("bm-autoplay")||i.getNamedItem("bm-autoplay").value;r.autoplay="false"!==a,r.name=i.getNamedItem("data-name")?i.getNamedItem("data-name").value:i.getNamedItem("data-bm-name")?i.getNamedItem("data-bm-name").value:i.getNamedItem("bm-name")?i.getNamedItem("bm-name").value:"","false"===
....
// I couldn't add more of the code because the caracters would be too much.
```


Additionally I'm asking, Is this supported by all browsers?
````